# Complex scroll android

Tags: android, scroll

I'm begin learning android and I want to code a function like that http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScCJ40Ugxfw.I intend to use 2 scroll ( a superview is listview scroll left and right, a child listview scroll upd and down for each page of scroll left and right. Is it ok?

Comment: For right/left better is [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: 
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
and
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/
maybe, it can help you